# What definitions can "blessed" have when referred to people and events?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

I'm wondering if "blessed" can refer to either of the following when used to describe a person or event:

1) Being favored by a higher power

2) Just being fortunate/happy

Here are a few sample sentences:

"I feel blessed for the opportunity to work on Project X."

"It was a blessed opportunity to work on Project X."

The first sentence describes the author as blessed, while the second describes the opportunity itself (the event) as blessed.

Could a secularist or atheist write either of the sentences if they just want to convey that they're happy or feel fortunate for being able to work on Project X?

For some context: Assume the sentence would be in writing (so no pronunciation involved), and in the piece of writing the author never discloses their beliefs.

Also, I've looked up the definition of "blessed" on quite a few online dictionaries, and the consensus seems to be that it can mean either definition 1) or 2). So my question is mainly about whether "blessed" can still mean either definition when used to describe a person or event (as in both my sample sentences). For example, can a person be said to be both "favored by a divine power" and "happy" while an event can only be one? The dictionaries never went into detail here.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "blessed" is **1) Being favored by a higher power**.  People use it in situation **2) just being fortunate/happy**, when they want to proclaim that it is the result of **1)**.

Could a secularist or atheist write either of the sentences if they just want to convey that they're happy or feel fortunate for being able to work on Project X?  Sure, it's not illegal.  For example, politicians who might have little personal religious conviction will spout phrases like that and engage in displays of religiosity when campaigning in an area with a religious population.  But an a-religious person speaking honestly would not used "blessed" in that way (or likely any way if referring to their own experience).

Comment: You could mention the different pronunciations 'bless-ed' (holy) and 'blest' (lucky).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, "For some context: Assume the sentence would be in writing (so no pronunciation involved)" (next to last paragraph of question)

Comment: Your final sentence is very much a cultural matter. In the south of the united states, at least, atheists and other expressly non-religious people refer to themselves use 'blessed' regularly - while its denotation may not be strictly accurate, its actual use is widespread and undeniable.